# Avoiding having to put DLLs in CWD

Tags: python, windows, dll, ctypes

Is it possible to avoid having to put DLLs in the same directory as the scripts using them?

I would like to be able to put a DLL in one place and have it reachable by any script.

`ctypes.CDLL()` seems to only find DLLs if they are in the CWD. Putting them somewhere in sys.path, or in System32 doesn't work.

Specifically I'm trying to get `UniCurses` to find `pdcurses.dll` without it being in the the CWD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
pdcurses_path = ctypes.util.find_library('pdcurses.dll')
if pdcurses_path:
    pdcurses = ctypes.CDLL(pdcurses_path)
else:
    raise ImportError("could not locate pdcurses.dll library")
```

Comment: Thanks! After trying the above it turns out `find_library()` is in `ctypes.util` not `ctypes`.

Comment: Acorn, the official docs agree with you, so I've edited the post. http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html

Comment: I also just realized that I hadn't assigned the return value from CDLL to anything, so it would be pretty useless to ctypes or Python.